# Yield return request never returns

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm having a problem with my courotine. The yield return actually never goes anywhere.. It just doesn't want to return in the Webplayer build. In the Editor it works perfectly fine, no problems yielding at all. This is my IEnumerator that i'm starting.

```
public IEnumerator CreateChannel(string ChannelName) {
    string urlRequest = "http://hiddenForSecurityPurposes.com/game/AddChannel.aspx?ChannelName=" + ChannelName;
    WWW request = new WWW(urlRequest);

    yield return request;
    //It never reaches here.. It runs this IEnumerator, but the yield return never returns itself.

    print("It got yielded");
}
```

Again, quick note. This does work fully out in the Editor, but not in Webplayer, which is what I'm exporting my game to.

Comment: It doesn't reach `print("It got yielded");`? Of course not, because you're returning above.

Comment: No but in Unity, the yield return simply yields the data from the request and returns it back into the request variable, and then proceeds on, atleast that is how it's suppose to work according to the Unity API.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/400/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html

Comment: Way ahead of you Alex. I've done every possible step in there already. The weird thing is that it works in the Editor but not in the actual build.

Comment: How are you using the iterator you're creating? (In the normal C# language, it's not up to the iterator block to "proceed on" - it's only when the *caller* asks for the next item from the iterator.)

Comment: I'm simply running this IEnumerator through a StartCourotine if that's what your asking.

Comment: Yes but listen, as I said, it works and runs in the actual Editor. The code runs fine.. But in the build it doesn't, what would be the difference that make it not work there?

Comment: It may come down to some quirk of WebPlayer security policy implementation. You might try running a debug build, and checking the [runtime log](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LogFiles.html) for helpful information. Have you confirmed the security file's encoding is as expected?

Comment: Good call.. Didn't think about that. This is the error i'm getting, which should actually happen since my crossdomain is there.. http://pastebin.com/YsrH2mmC The crossdomain http://kevinjp.dk/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 0):

Is your Webplayer and the domain you are trying to reach on the same url/server? If not, you need to put a **crossdomain.xml** to the root of the server you are trying to reach. In your case that would be `http://hiddenForSecurityPurposes.com/crossdomain.xml`

Comment: I did what Rutter suggested above, to make a debug build and look through the log. Which is that i'm getting.. http://pastebin.com/YsrH2mmC But I can ensure you the crosdomain file is there, right here: http://kevinjp.dk/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 0):

from [this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html): "Note: The security sandbox present in web-player builds prevents you from accessing content not hosted the server where the webplayer is hosted."

It seems like you have to have the game hosted on the same server, with or without a crossdomain.xml. However, [this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html) states otherwise.

I'm led to believe that the crossdomain.xml file is necessary for communicating with the server from a mobile, but with the webplayer, the game must be on the same server. It seems like the people who write the documentation may disagree with themselves...